# UIGestureRecognizer that cancels when touchup outside of targetView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have a UIView of which I want to know when the user is doing:

`touchDownInside` (to highlight the view)

`touchUpInside`  (to confirm the action)

`touchUpOutside` (to cancel and reset the hightlight)

what gestureRecognizer can do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go though these four methods also which your view can override to handle the four distinct touch events:

1) finger or fingers touches the screen

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

2)finger or fingers move across the screens(this message repeatedly as a finger moves.)

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

3)finger or fingers is removed from the screen

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

4) a system event,interrupts a touch before it ends

```
-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this implementing the touches methods itself, why do you need gesture recognizer?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

The above function for touch down.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

The above function for touch up. And the combination of both for cancel.